# Updated from Drupal 8.9.20 to 9.0.0, but can't run update.php due to errors

Tags: views, updating

Here's what I get when attempted to run update.php:

**Requirements problem**

Errors found

**MISSING UPDATES FOR: SYSTEM**
The installed version of the System module is too old to update. Update to a version prior to 9.0.0 first (missing updates: system_post_update_layout_plugin_schema_change, system_post_update_entity_reference_autocomplete_match_limit).

**MISSING UPDATES FOR: TAXONOMY**
The installed version of the Taxonomy module is too old to update. Update to a version prior to 9.0.0 first (missing updates: taxonomy_post_update_configure_status_field_widget).

**MISSING UPDATES FOR: TEXT**
The installed version of the Text module is too old to update. Update to a version prior to 9.0.0 first (missing updates: text_post_update_add_required_summary_flag).

**MISSING UPDATES FOR: VIEWS**
The installed version of the Views module is too old to update. Update to a version prior to 9.0.0 first (missing updates: views_post_update_limit_operator_defaults, views_post_update_remove_core_key).

Comment: How exactly did you perform the upgrade? From what exact version of Drupal 8 to what exact version of Drupal 9? Update your question, please.

Comment: Thanks, leymannx. So, I was going from 8.9.20 to 9.0.0. I'd installed the upgrade status module and made sure everything was compliant before updating.

Comment: Update your question please and add this. No one should have to look in the comments to find crucial information there. Please also tell us if you performed database updates on 8.9.20.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So far, the question just give a list of error messages; it doesn't explain what you don't understand in fixing the issue. Actually, the question isn't even a question, as it doesn't explicitly ask any question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the messages: "Update to a version prior to 9.0.0 first". Upgrade to the newest version of Drupal 8 first before upgrading to Drupal 9.

"Update" means also executing schema updates, either with update.php or with `drush updatedb`.

Comment: Thanks, cilefen! Yep, totally did that. I installed the upgrade status module, made it all compliant, had my site at Drupal 8.9.20. It all looked so good. Then I got this when I updated to Drupal 9. 

Happy to provide more info and truly appreciate the help!

Comment: @Dan – Did you perform database updates on 8.9.20?

Comment: @leymannx. I *believe* I did, but now that you mention it, I'm not 100% sure. Great point. I can reload the old db and go through the process again. I'll update with results.